# Normal forms of proofs in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: intuitionistic-logic

In [this post](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/), Andrej Bauer says:

> There is a theorem about normal forms of proofs in intuitionistic logic which tells us that every proof of a negation can be rearranged so that it ends with the inference rule cited above

Can someone point me to a text on "normal forms of proofs in intuitionistic logic" and to this theorem?

Comment: The standard texts are _Natural Deduction_ by Dag Prawitz (1965) and _Basic Proof Theory_ by Troelstra & Schwichtenberg (2nd ed., 2000). In particular, you may want to take a look at §IV.1 and §IV.2 of _Natural Deduction_ (theorem 1 and 2, respectively) and chapter 6 of _Basic Proof Theory_, theorem 6.1.8, and, especially, §6.2, proposition 6.2.4.